# implement Z3 with cmake in using pre-released version

Tags: c++, cmake, z3

```
set(Z3_DIR "../../z3-4.8.8-x64-osx-10.14.6")
include_directories(${Z3_DIR}/include)
set(Z3_LIBRARIES ${Z3_DIR}/bin/)
add_executable(exa main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(exa ${Z3_LIBRARIES})
```

I download the pre-released version of Z3, but the files structures are quite different with machine built one. How could I write the include directories to use the pre-released version in my cpp-project. 
tree:

```
├── LICENSE.txt
├── bin
│   ├── Microsoft.Z3.deps.json
│   ├── Microsoft.Z3.dll
│   ├── com.microsoft.z3.jar
│   ├── libz3.a
│   ├── libz3.dylib
│   ├── libz3java.dylib
│   ├── python
│   │   ├── example.py
│   │   └── z3
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── __init__.pyc
│   │       ├── z3.py
│   │       ├── z3.pyc
│   │       ├── z3consts.py
│   │       ├── z3consts.pyc
│   │       ├── z3core.py
│   │       ├── z3core.pyc
│   │       ├── z3num.py
│   │       ├── z3num.pyc
│   │       ├── z3poly.py
│   │       ├── z3poly.pyc
│   │       ├── z3printer.py
│   │       ├── z3printer.pyc
│   │       ├── z3rcf.py
│   │       ├── z3rcf.pyc
│   │       ├── z3types.py
│   │       ├── z3types.pyc
│   │       ├── z3util.py
│   │       └── z3util.pyc
│   └── z3
└── include
    ├── z3++.h
    ├── z3.h
    ├── z3_algebraic.h
    ├── z3_api.h
    ├── z3_ast_containers.h
    ├── z3_fixedpoint.h
    ├── z3_fpa.h
    ├── z3_macros.h
    ├── z3_optimization.h
    ├── z3_polynomial.h
    ├── z3_rcf.h
    ├── z3_spacer.h
    ├── z3_v1.h
    └── z3_version.h
```

With following cmakelists, the fatal error:

the out put here `/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/bin/cmake -S/Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test -B/Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test/build/CMakeFiles /Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/exa.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/exa.dir/depend
cd /Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test/build && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test /Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test /Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test/build /Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test/build /Users/charles/guanqin/analysis/z3test/build/CMakeFiles/exa.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/exa.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/exa.dir/build
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable exa

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.17.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/exa.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/exa.dir/main.o  -o exa   -L../z3-4.8.8-x64-osx-10.14.6/bin/libz3.dylib  -Wl,-rpath,../z3-4.8.8-x64-osx-10.14.6/bin/libz3.dylib -lz3 
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L../z3-4.8.8-x64-osx-10.14.6/bin/libz3.dylib'
ld: library not found for -lz3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [exa] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/exa.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you building from a separate build directory? Is `Z3_DIR` relative to the source directory? What does the full compile invocation look like? Edit your question with the output of `make VERBOSE=1`

Comment: I tried to add        `LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Z3_DIR}/bin/)`    but it looks like that couldn't help me find the library

Comment: You're getting an error from the compiler. Adding extra link flags (which comes _after_ compilation) will not magically solve this error. Moreover, `link_directories` takes directories as argument, not files.

Comment: it still can't find the z3   '''[ 50%] Linking CXX executable exa
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L../z3-4.8.8-x64-osx-10.14.6/bin'
ld: library not found for -lz3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [exa] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/exa.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: EITHER pass the full filename to `target_link_libraries`, OR set `link_directories` to `${Z3_DIR}/bin` and `target_link_libraries(exa z3)`.

Comment: thanks, sir.  After I change Z3_DIR to the absolute path, the compiler goes well.